# Ajax parsererror with JSON in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I'm doing an application web for a school and I'm stuck when trying to edit a student. I want the user to click in the row of and specific student and then open a form with his data.

I have to do an ajax request, so I can call my php function (the one which makes the query on my db) and load the data in the form. This is my jQuery code for the ajax request:

```
//When you click in the table students, in some element whose class is edit ...
    $("#tblAlumnos").on("click", ".editar", function(event) {

    var rowID = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../ajax/',
        data: {'table': 'alumnos', 'action': 'carga', 'ids': rowID},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(result.nombre);

        },

        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                alert(jqXHR);
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

The ajax request calls the method to get the data from my db:

```
function cargaAlumno($ids) {

        require 'db.php';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Alumnos WHERE ID=$ids";
        $result = $conexion->query($sql);


        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();

            $nombre = $row['Nombre'];
            $apellidos = $row['Apellidos'];
            $telefono = $row['Telefono'];
            $usuario = $row['Usuario'];
            $contrasena = $row['Contrasena'];

            $result = array();
            $result["nombre"] = $nombre;
            $result["apellidos"] = $apellidos;
            $result["telefono"] = $telefono;
            $result["usuario"] = $usuario;
            $result["contrasena"] = $contrasena;

            ChromePhp::warn($result);
            ChromePhp::warn(json_encode($result));
            echo json_encode($result);

        }

    }
```

This method has to return a JSON to the ajax request, but the success method is never reached because of the error: parsererror.

I've tried with dataType: 'json' (this is when I have the error) and without it (it thinks its html). I also have tried with and without contentType and in my php: header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8').

My json encoded looks like this:

```
{"nombre":"Susana","telefono":"56765336","usuario":"susa"}
```

I don't know if I need some more methods because I'm doing it in Wordpress or I have something wrong in my code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: what error you have got ?

Comment: parsererror when the ajax request gets the response of my php function @SubhashShipu

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in Wordpress, I'd use the built in `wpdb` to handle the db connection and results. Like so:

```
function cargaAlumno() {

    global $wpdb;
    $ids = $_POST['ids'];

    $sql = $wpdb->get_results( 
        $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * 
        FROM Alumnos
        WHERE id = '$ids'
        ")
    );

    echo json_encode($sql);

    exit();

    }
```

Also remember this goes into your themes functions.php file.

Remember to hook it into the wp_ajax hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cargaAlumno', 'cargaAlumno' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cargaAlumno', 'cargaAlumno' );
```

Then in your ajax:

```
$("#tblAlumnos").on("click", ".editar", function(event) {

    var rowID = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl, //this is a wordpress ajaxurl hook
        data: {'table': 'alumnos', 'action': 'cargaAlumno', 'ids': rowID}, // You didn't use the correct action name, it's your function name i.e. cargaAlumno 
        //dataType: 'json', dont need this
        success: function(result) {
           //Parse the data
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(obj[0].nombre); // I'm guessing nombre is your db column name

        },

        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                alert(jqXHR);
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

This js file needs to be added into your theme to work in conjunction with the above reworked function()

Let me know if you need anymore help or have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now that my function has to be in functions.php and that I have to put its name in the action, but the result is the same: 
- if I have the line dataType: 'json' there's a parsererror with status 200
- if I don't have it the result it's html and I have the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I don't know where the problem is because I think the json returned by my function has a valid structure, but ajax doesn't recognized it as json. Do you have any idea why this keeps happening?

Comment: That's odd. Do you have any redirects in place for the site? Example, if not logged in, redirect to login page. Or if subscriber dont allow them in the dashboard?

Comment: I have session_start() to ckeck if the user has logged in and if he doesn't redirect him to an error page at the begginig of my .php classes, but I don't have it in functions.php or in my .js

Comment: I had a similar issue. I had a redirect. The fix was to remove the redirect I added then added a template_redirect which is a wordpress hook.

Comment: I removed the redirect and nothing has changed. It keeps returning html instead of json.

Comment: Can you send the html response? Because this will give more details. Alternatively you can try increase the memory with `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '240M');` in your wp-config.php

Comment: How can I send it? It's too long to put it here, but basically it's my web page with menu and footer and the content of the page it's the json I want to read in the success function. I already have the memory limit as 256M.

Comment: Right now it can be a number of things, what I'd suggest is looking at the advised way of adding ajax in plugins, this works the same for themes too > https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Also remember to remove your redirects for testing. This is probably where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're only providing particular lines of your code or this is the whole thing, anyway this is definitely **NOT** how you should handle AJAX requests in WordPress:

- You should use `wp_ajax_` for actions that requires authentication or `wp_ajax_nopriv_` for ones that doesn't
- You should create an action for this function and send your request through `admin-ajax.php` using `admin_url()`
- You should definitely secure your requests by creating nonces using `wp_create_nonce()` and verify it using `wp_verify_nonce()`
- You should restrict direct access to your AJAX file while checking `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`

There's no need to require db.php since you're already working within functions.php and the db connection is already established.

Use the below method instead:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$query_results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

To wrap it up, please follow the below structure:

**Frontend (*php* file):**

```
<?php
$ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce("change_to_action_name");
$ajax_link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=change_to_action_name&nonce=' . $ajax_nonce);
?> 
<a class="do_ajax" href="#" data-ajax_link="<?php echo ajax_link; ?>" data-ajax_param="other_param">DO AJAX</a>
<input id="param" value="" />
```

**Script File (*js* file):**

```
$('.do_ajax').click(function () {
        var ajax_link = $(this).attr('data-ajax_link');
        var param = $(this).attr('data-ajax_param');

        if (ajax_link && param) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                url: ajax_link,
                data: {
                    param: param,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.type == "success") {

                    /*Get/updated returned vals from ajax*/
                    $('#param').val(response.new_param);
                        console.log('ajax was successful');

                    } else if (response.type == "error") {
                       console.log('ajax request had errors');
                    }else{
                        console.log('ajax request had errors');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('ajax not sent');
        }
    });
```

**Functions File (*functions.php* file):**

```
add_action("wp_ajax_change_to_action_name", "change_to_action_name");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_change_to_action_name", "change_to_action_name");
function change_to_action_name()
{
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['nonce'], "change_to_action_name")) {
        exit("You think you are smart?");
    }

    $param = $_REQUEST['param'];

    /*php actions goes here*/
    $actions_success=0;
    if($actions_success){

    /*Query db and update vals here*/

        $new_param = "new_val";
        $result['new_param'] = $new_param;
        $result['type'] = "success";

    }else{
        $result['type'] = "error";
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $result = json_encode($result);
        echo $result;
    } else {
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    }
    die();
}
```

Your current code contains many security flaws, so it's very recommended that you update it and use the above method.

Cheers!

Comment: From what I know, `$wpdb->prepare` handles the security. Also what is `$actions_success`?

Comment: $actions_success is a flag that should be set to 1 whenever a specific function is successful to be able to send a related response using $result['type'], that's just a demo anyway. Furthermore, `$wpdb->prepare` handles security for database queries (and is best practice anyway) and is not related to the AJAX security explained in the example above.